# Disable max_user_connections limits

Tags: php, mysql

I have a project which returns the follow error

```
User already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections
```

I know it is a MySQL error, and I can increase `max_user_connections`, but, I want to disable the verification of simultaneous accesses. Is it possible? How?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Current `max_user_connections` is 30 and `max_connections` is 300, and I don't persist connection.

Comment: What's wrong with making it arbitrarily large?

Comment: It is one idea, but, I think if I can disable, is more secure.

Comment: What is you max_user_connections value? I would be very wary of arbitrarily changing any of your connection limits without having a good reason to do so.

Comment: @GabrielSantos How would disabling the max user connections make it any more secure?

Comment: Not secure of hacking, etc. It is safe users always will get what they want, the website up.

Comment: @arxanas Exactly.  This would actually potentially make your application less secure and less stable.

Comment: Secure of errors and scripts down: `Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DBCFactory::__construct() must be an instance of ConectionFactory, null given`, because connection are not stabilished.

Comment: You could check for null, like a good programmer...

Comment: @arxanas lool. I know I can verify if connection stabilished, but, if not stabilished because of max user connections, I can't get the website working.

Comment: @arxanas And I only the friend of programmer of this project, so, I can't change codes..

Comment: @GabrielSantos What are total max_connections  Are there other DB users that utilize this server or is this a single user scenario for the application/DB server? What is the typical number of open connections over any given time on this server (i.e. should there tpyically only be one or two open connection but sometimes it spikes to 30, are are you running at or near 30 all the time)?  Are you using any kind of connection pool management (probably not with PHP, but figured I would ask)? Are persistent connections being used?

Comment: @MikeBrant I have about 3 projects with shared core, each with your individual database and user, all in same server. `max_connections` of 300. Not persisted.

Comment: @GabrielSantos Are you using one DB connection per each page load (i.e. using a singleton or modern DB abstraction which enforces a single DB connection to be used throughout the entire script execution)?  What sort of user traffic is the site getting (i.e. PHP script requests per second)?

Comment: Single connection with multiple querys. I have High traffic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the mysql config file.

Set max_user_connections=0.

Comment: You typically don't want any particular user being able to gobble up all the connections to your database. You are much better off finding out what the actual problem is.  Do you legitimately not have enough connections available to that user to meet your load level? Are you not reusing database connections efficiently? Do you have long running queries that are stacking connections, etc.? While setting this limit may make your problem go away temporarily, it may also lead to a more catastrophic failure down the line.

Comment: You are absolutely right I don't endorse unlimited connections but I'd need more information to give a better solution.